# Accessing Flask WS APIs over intranet -

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, json, windows

I have 2 scripts - A.py and B.py, and both are Flask apps.
*A.py* renders a web page and acts as my UI taking inputs from user.
*B.py* is hold the main logic and has a web service API being called by *A.py*.

Both run as flask app services in localhost from different ports - 5001 and 5002, respectively.

My doubts -

1) Every time I make any changes to my B.py (or A.py), do i need to stop and restart the services?

2) I'm currently running both the services from local machine for proof-of-concept purposes. If I use WSGI (thinking of *Bottle*), will it be accessible from other machines over intranet?

I'm on Windows 10 (64-bit), Python 3.6 and Flask 1.1.1

Please advise.

---

Edit 1) Added OS and Python version details.

Answer (score 0):

1) **YES**. the updates won't be visible not until your restart your webservice. ( Both by the way ).

2) **Gunicorn** works well with Flask as a wsgi app. I'm not sure how to answer your question. All i can say is that i have webservices deployed to production with both Gunicorn+ Flask and Flask only, and they are both accessible over **internet**. Only difference is that Flask is not meant for production deployment, only for testing purposes.

Comment: You must be on Unix environment, but I'm on Windows which is not supported by Gunicorn. So, I'm evaluating Bottle, at this moment.

Comment: Oh. Yeah i deployed the models on a Ubuntu server